# Add generated content in generated div with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamic, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to make this happen using an ng-repeat

```
<div class="lightlighten seperatediv">
   <label class="item item-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="group">
      <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
   </label>
    <label class="item item-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="group">
      <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
   </label>
    <label class="item item-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="group">
      <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
   </label>
    <label class="item item-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="group">
      <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
   </label>
    <label class="item item-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="group">
      <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
   </label>
    <label class="item item-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="group">
      <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
   </label>
    <label class="item item-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="group">
      <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
   </label>
</div>

<div class="darklighten seperatediv">
    <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
</div>

<div class="lightlighten seperatediv">
    <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
</div>

<div class="darklighten seperatediv">
    <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
     <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group">
       <img ng-src="img/avatars/1.png" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Notice the change of the class attribute of the div (lightlighten and darklighten).

In the beginning it didn't look that hard, but when I started with the ng-repeat thing got pretty complicated.

What the ng-repeat (or some other kind of method) should do:
Make a new div every 7 items (not variable) with a changing classname (lightlighten/darklighten) and add new items in the "freshed" div.

I've already coded this, but the most important part is obviously missing

```
<div ng-repeat="image in allImages">
                <label class="item item-radio">
                <input type="radio" name="group" ng-click="changeAvatar(image.id)" ng-checked={{image.active}}>
                  <img ng-src={{image.src}} />
                </label>
              </div>
```

A class can be generated like this. It's a sample but it will probably be required to get this done.

```
ng-class="{ 'darklighten': $index % 2 == 0}"
```

Could somebody help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `$even` context variable like this

```
<div ng-repeat="image in allImages" ng-class="{'dark': $even, 'light' : $odd}"> </div>
```